# Google ScatterChart from uploaded csv file

Tags: charts, google-visualization

How can plot a Google Scatterchartfrom an uploaded csv file?

It is showing a blank page.

I tried the following code:

Loading the scripts:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>
```

Then I got this part from an example:

```
<script> // wait till the DOM is loaded
    $(function() { 
        // grab the CSV
        $.get("https://www.batemo.de/wp-content/uploads/general/data_chart_gravimetric.csv", function(csvString) { 
            // display the contents of the CSV
            $("#chart").html(csvString); }); }); 

            // load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                // grab the CSV
                $.get("https://www.batemo.de/wp-content/uploads/general/data_chart_gravimetric.csv", function(csvString) {
                    // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array 
                    var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

                    // this new DataTable object holds all the data
                    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

                    // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
                    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); view.setColumns([0,1]);
                    var options = {};

                    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                    chart.draw(view, options);
                }); }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the example has an error.

the brackets at the end of the following line...

```
$("#chart").html(csvString); }); }); <-- these two sets of brackets
```

need to move down below the rest of the code,
here is the full, corrected snippet...

```
$(function() {
    // grab the CSV
    $.get("https://www.batemo.de/wp-content/uploads/general/data_chart_gravimetric.csv", function(csvString) {
        // display the contents of the CSV
        $("#chart").html(csvString);

        // load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            // grab the CSV
            $.get("https://www.batemo.de/wp-content/uploads/general/data_chart_gravimetric.csv", function(csvString) {
                // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
                var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

                // this new DataTable object holds all the data
                var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

                // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); view.setColumns([0,1]);
                var options = {};

                var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                chart.draw(view, options);
            }); }
     }); });
```

Comment: I copied your code, but it doesn´t display anything.

Comment: have you checked the browser's console for errors? (press F12)